# What is a habitual sentence and in what does it differ other legal sentences?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Here are some examples:

> He was facing five years on each count and you are also facing a **habitual sentence**, she told him, and you can actually get double.
>
> Prosecutors counter that it is more common for a defendant facing a **habitual sentence** to make an "open plea" - legal jargon for what is poetically termed "throwing himself on the mercy of the court."
>
> He's turned so much around, and it doesn't make sense for him to be facing a **habitual sentence** now,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Habitual offenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_offender) (aka *repeat offenders*, or *career criminals*) are people who are convicted for another crime after being previously convicted. A habitual sentence is the sentence a habitual offender serves.

The law varies, but usually the punishment is more severe for people who repeatedly break the law—“you can actually get double” refers to this.